# Retrieve data from a specific column based on multiple criteria (comma separated values) in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to make a Google Sheet-formula that matches words in a cell based on a multiple criteria (comma separated) cell and returns a specific value.

**Sheet1** contains phrases and a formula:

| Phrases | Formula |
| --- | --- |
| fruit bat | {formula} |
| fruit bats | {formula} |
| fruitbat | {formula} |
| big fruit bat | {formula} |
| fruit bat eating orange | {formula} |
| orange fruit | {formula} |
| apple is a good fruit | {formula} |
| i like pie | {formula} |
| pies for lunch | {formula} |
| apple pie is better | {formula} |
| juice from apples | {formula} |

**Sheet2** search values (comma separated) and corresponding return values:

| Comma-separated search values | Return Value |
| --- | --- |
| fruit, bat | Animal - Bats |
| fruit, orange, bat | Animal - Orange bat |
| orange, fruit | Food - Orange |
| apple, fruit | Food - Apple |
| pie | Food - Pie |
| apple, pie | Food - Apple Pie |
| juice, apple | Beverage - Apple |

I want **Sheet1** to look like this in the end:

| Phrases | Formula |
| --- | --- |
| fruit bat | Animal - Bats |
| fruit bats | Animal - Bats |
| fruitbat | Animal - Bats |
| big fruit bat | Animal - Bats |
| fruit bat eating orange | Animal - Orange bat |
| orange fruit | Food - Orange |
| apple is a good fruit | Food - Apple |
| i like pie | Food - Pie |
| pies for lunch | Food - Pie |
| apple pie is better | Food - Apple Pie |
| juice from apples | Beverage - Apple |

Right now my formula looks like this:
`=IFNA(VLOOKUP(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(A2); LOWER(TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; SORT(Sheet2!A:A; 1; 0))))); Sheet2!A:B; 2; 0))`

The formula correctly returns "Food - Pie" on the phrases "i like pie" and "pies for lunch". It incorrectly returns "Food - Pie" on the phrase "apple pie is better", and all other rows are empty.

Is it possible to modify the current formula so it's compatible with search for comma separated values?

Note that the matching should be wildcard, and not dependent on spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If and only if custom formula is an option due to unavailability of other answers, see the code below.

#### Code:

```
function getRegexMatch(string, exprs) {
  // sort descending based on search length to get max matches
  exprs = exprs.sort(function(a, b){
    return b[0].length - a[0].length;
  });
  // filter pattern where number of matches is equal to number of search values
  var output = exprs.filter(function([expr, value]){ 
    var patterns = expr.split(", ");
    var result = patterns.filter(function(pattern) {
      if(RegExp(pattern).exec(string))
        return true;
    });
    if (patterns.length == result.length)
      return true;
  });
  // return the value of max match pattern
  return output[0][1];
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- Search-return value pair were sorted based on the length of its search values (longer length comes first) before processing as we want to get the return value where all search values are matching the string. This is to prevent returning the value where not all search values match and other search values that have lower number of matches than the number of search values (e.g. `fruit bat eating orange` returning `Animal - Orange bat` instead of `Animal - Bats` which comes first if not sorted)
- Given that we sorted the search-return value pairs based on its search value length (longer length comes first), it means that it will always encounter the best possible match first.
- So when we see the first match, return it immediately.
- The code above is called one by one per cell, but it can be modified to just call it once and return all column A's matches on column B.